# Multiplying and add numbers inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a field that matches this:

```
"invoice_items" : [
    {
        "price" : 10,
        "quantity" : 600
    },
    {
        "price" : 499.99,
        "quantity" : 1
    }
]
```

I was looking to aggregate it and get a total, so multiply price by quantity and add the two together, there can be any number of items in the array. The last one that I tried was:

```
[{
    $match: {
        "is_closed": false
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        invoice_items: "$invoice_items"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        count: {
            $multiply: ["$invoice_items.price", "$invoice_items.quantity"]
        }
    }
}]
```

Which I thought would give something back but it only errored out saying "The field 'invoice_items' must be an accumulator object"

Comment: could you please explain bit more and post the expected output

Comment: Could you explain wasn't isn't clear, all I'm wanting to do is for each document multiply price by quantity for each item in the invoice_item array and add them together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Basically you need to use [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate over the `invoice_items` array and [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to add all the `invoice_items` values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "count": {
      "$sum": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$invoice_items",
          "in": { "$multiply": ["$$this.price", "$$this.quantity"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```